# How to automatically load flyspell-mode when Markdown (.md, .mdwn) file is open?

Tags: init-file, flyspell

When editing Markdown files (.md, .mdwn, etc.) and Mediawiki files (.mw), I almost always need to have flyspell-mode loaded.  How to have that automatically happen via configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in your .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

It will enable flyspell-mode whenever markdown-mode is entered; i.e. when you open markdown files.

Comment: Adding `(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)` had no effect AFAICT. After restarting Emacs and opening a .mdwn file, the mini-buffer shows the Markdown-mode is automatically enabled, but not the flyspell-mode.

Comment: Revisiting this thread after two years, now in Emacs 25.2, your solution seems to work now. I verified that Flyspell mode is turned on by restarting Emacs, opening a new file test.md, and seeing that Flyspell is listed in `M-x describe-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers recommending adding `flyspell-mode` as a `markdown-mode-hook` function. Perhaps the problem is that `flyspell-mode` is a toggle.  There is also `turn-on-flyspell`, defined like so:

```
(defun turn-on-flyspell ()
  "Unconditionally turn on Flyspell mode."
  (flyspell-mode 1))
```

This is a built-in function which accomplishes the same thing as in marcanuy's answer.

So, this should do what you want, unconditionally:

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
(add-hook 'mediawiki-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

Comment: To avoid those problems, minor modes were changed years ago so that calling `foo-mode` from Elisp (e.g. via a major mode hook) just turns the mode ON rather than doing the toggling that happens via that function is called interactively.  So no: you don't need to resort to `turn-on-foo-mode` (these functions are relics from the time before I made this change).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Stefan. I wondered why qazwsx had trouble with using the minor mode function directly. I also didn't realize at first that this was a two-year-old thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Base on Trebuchette's answer:

```lisp
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'mediawiki-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

---

But if you want to turn on `flyspell-mode` while editing text files in various major-modes, you can just use:

```lisp
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

this will works because `markdown-mode` and `mediawiki-mode` are base on `text-mode`. Analogously, we use `prog-mode-hook` to setup common programming environment.

Comment: Adding `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)` to .emacs has no effect when I restarted Emacs and opened a `.mdwn` file.  The `.mdwn` file did triggered Markdown-mode though.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and finally found a [solution](https://simpleit.rocks/writing-in-emacs-checking-spelling-style-and-grammar/) that works:

```
(dolist (hook '(markdown-mode-hook))
      (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1))))
```

*Tested in GNU Emacs 25.1*

---

Not tested this but should also work for other modes like mediawiki:

```
(dolist (hook '(markdown-mode-hook mediawiki-mode-hook))
      (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1))))
```